# bootstrap open tab from a different page link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that has bootstrap tabs on it. I am trying to open a particular tab from a different page. I tried to link like a bookmark example http://localhost/view-customer#enquiries etc. But it's not working. Is calling the link from a query. The query script is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
$("#customers").autocomplete({
 source: "fetch_customers.php?cc=<?php echo $agencyid; ?>",
 minLength: 2,
 select: function(event, ui) {
var code = ui.item.id;
if(code != '#') {
location.href = '/view-customer/' + code + '#enquiries';
         }
 },
open: function(event, ui) {
$(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
 }
});
});
```

We can see the location.href links to http://localhost/view-customer/a1224#enquiries

and view-customer page looks like this.

```
 <div id="enquiries" name="enquiries" class="tab-pane fade in rowCSS">

<div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
               @include('enquiries_table')
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Its a simple concept but still why its not opening the tab. Might be bootstrap tabs works in a different way than normal html. I am not sure. Can anyone pls guide me.

Comment: Or do i need to use <section ...>

Comment: Can anyone pls help me. Guess need to add a hash in my location.href.

Comment: You are halfway there. Now, you have a unique target identifier for each tab in your URL, i.e. **#enquiries**. Now, on the page(having tabs), read the URL to extract the target identifier and just activate the appropriate tab using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the tab target identifier, use the following code to target specific tab on your page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const url = location.href; // get the browser URL
  const regEx = /\#(.*)/g; // match string starting with a "#" character
  const matched = url.match(regEx); // returns ['#enquiries']

  if(matched.length){
    let target = matched[0];
    // click on the target tab
    $(target).click(); // $('#enquiries').click();
  }
});
```